# Get the text inside <font> tags VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Hey guys i just started coding using Visual Basics and i just can't seem to figure out how to get the text inside a `<font>` and `<b>`
I am using the built in web browser in Visual Basics

The HTML page contains

`<font size="1"><b>Bob</b></font>`

I have tried

```
Dim theElementCollection As HtmlElementCollection = Nothing
theElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("font")
For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection
If InStr(curElement.GetAttribute("size").ToString, "1") Then
TextBox1.Text = curElement.InnerText
 End If
 Next
```

I want to get `Bob` and add it into a text box. 
i researched regular expressions and parsing but couldn't understand anything since i'm new to vb :(

Comment: Instead of down voting can you at least point me to where i can find a solution -.-

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that has the same problem i solved it myself :)

`Dim PageElements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("font")
        For Each CurElement As HtmlElement In PageElements
            TextBox1.Text = CurElement.InnerText
        Next`

The code above works perfect!